# División solo con sumas

Tags: c

Buenas estoy tratando de hacer un programa que introducido el dividendo y el divisor sea capaz de hacer la división solo con sumas, y no entiendo en que parte me estoy equivocando. El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
 int x,y,i;
printf("Introduce el dividendo: \n");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("Introduce el divisor: \n");
scanf("%d",&y);

for (i=0;x!=y;++i);{
        x+=x;
  }
printf("La division sale: %d",i);
}
```

Comment: Estás mezclando variables entre sí, la variable `i` no hace nada, además de que estás sumando consigo mismo el dividendo, cuando debe ser el divisor hasta que iguale al otro al sumarle el resto, si lo hay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como menciona [Francisco Javier](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/263891/francisco-javier) estás sumando el dividendo, en lugar del divisor que es lo que corresponde. Se me hace más legible acumular la suma en otra variable, y tratar de poner variables más descriptivas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x,y,i=0,suma=0;
    printf("Introduce el dividendo: \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Introduce el divisor: \n");
    scanf("%d",&y);

    while(suma < x) {
        suma=suma+y;
        i++;
    }
    printf("La division sale: %d",i);
    return 0;
}
```